# An alternative for Google+ comments for Blogger-based blog

Tags: hosted, comment-system

My blog is run using blogger.com and can be commented on using Google+, but doesn't get many comments - I think because not that many people really use Google+ since I do have quite a lot of activity on my forums.

I want to replace Google+ and was looking for alternatives.

Requirements

- Easy to incorporate into Blogger-based blog within HTML website
- Allows users to easily comment if they have either Facebook or Twitter account
- Control over harmful comments that I want to remove
- Preferably free

Comment: Please rewrite your question to list exactly all requirements. Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information then fix your question and click "reopen", thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Ive rewritten but I cant see how to reopen

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend **[Disqus](https://disqus.com/)**.

**Disqus** is a tool that provides comments and management for it. This tool is very popular among static blog sites because it's easy to hack them with Disqus. Regarding to your requirements, detail of this tool is explained as follows:

- *Easy to incorporate into blogger based blog within html website*. Yes, it is. You can incorporate Disqus into Blogger. The instruction is available [here](https://disqus.com/admin/blogger/).
- *Allows users to easily comment if they have either facebook or twitter account*. Sure, you can do it. You can control who people can give a comment (must be authenticated or not). Look at the snapshot below!

[image: Disqus comment with login]

- *Control over harmful comments that I want to remove*. You are not only provided comment but also a management comments by Disqus. So, you can control the undesirable comments.
- *Preferably free*. Disqus is **free**.

If you want to learn more about Disqus features, check [this](https://disqus.com/features/) page.

Comment: thx Disqus was what I was thinking of actually, but I dont know if it was the best choice.

Comment: Anytime. You can wait the other recommendation. So, you can choose what comment system suits with your use case.